# Predict values in Multidimensional Scaling (MDS) in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-science

I’m trying to use multidimensional scaling (MDS) in R.
Can I predict new values on test set based on the values that I receive from my training set?
I’m looking for something similar to what I’ve done in PCA for example:

```
prin_comp <- prcomp(pca.train, scale. = FALSE)
test.data <- predict(prin_comp, newdata = pca.test)
```

Thank you,
Ittai

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MDS` as the first of a three step process.

- Generate the `MDS` coordinates
- Apply a traditional clustering algorithm to the generated coordinates

  - E.g. `Kmeans` with `kmeans(x, K)` where you will need to supply the `K`=`number of clusters`

  Note that you will probably want to do some metrics of the generated clusters by 
  `cross validation` to ensure they are providing good labels for your existing data.
- Use the `kmeans` clusters to find the nearest centroid/cluster for each of 
   the new data
- Then you have a decision to make (as the modeler): do you apply the `mode` of the chosen cluster as the label for your new data? That is the simplest solution - but there can be other approaches.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what you wrote, can't I use the `predict` function based on the coefficient from the training model, and use the test data to predict new MDS values?